# nvarchar(max) comparing to length of a variable logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I altered a column in a table to `nvarchar(max)`. In the database the value of the max length for the column row is now -1.

How would I go about checking an insert to that column and making sure that the insert did not exceed the max value?

If it were a value like 2000 or so, I could just make sure the insert < column.length but because it is -1 the comparison would not work.

Would it best if I just hard code a -1 in my code?

Any ideas are appreciated, thank you

Comment: The -1 value in the meta-data for MAX types implies a maximum length of 2GB (1 billion Unicode characters).

Comment: If you are storing too many characters in a `MAX` column, then you should likely be storing files outside of the RDBMS and then storing the file path in the RDBMS instead.

Comment: @DanGuzman oh okay that makes sense, I will never be reaching that many unicode characters. I will probably just hardcode the -1. thank you

Comment: Presumably you need both the (max) capacity and unicode storage - because if you don't it's better to be more precise about the data type and length as using either where it's not actually necessary can have a detrimental impact on performance.